# In C++ how can we define a static const within a class that computes size of class member variables?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Does not compile:

```
class A
{
    int m_x;
public:
    static const int SIZE = sizeof(m_x);
};
```

I want to have `A::SIZE` equal the size of the member variable `m_x`. How can we do it?

I am using Visual Studio 2015. Here is the error:

```
1>c:\users\markk\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\b\b.cpp(10): error C2327: 'A::m_x': is not a type name, static, or enumerator
1>c:\users\markk\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\b\b.cpp(10): error C2065: 'm_x': undeclared identifier
```

Compilation command line:

```
/Yu"stdafx.h" /GS /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm /Od /sdl /Fd"x64\Debug\vc140.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /MDd /Fa"x64\Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Debug\" /Fp"x64\Debug\b.pch"
```

**EDIT 1**

Thanks to Stargateur. With a slight change it works on VS2015 too:

```
class A
{
    int m_x;
public:
    static const int SIZE;
};

const int A::SIZE = sizeof(A::m_x);
```

Turned out easier than I thought.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ixMr4kRkJft1c9PB

Comment: Works [fine here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/211cd37638375b76). What are you asking about? You're not going to tell us you missed the semicolon after that class declaration, do you?

Comment: in c++03 it doesn't work, but it would be clearer with the actual error message... 14k rep you should know that.

Comment: Of course, stupid me. Added the error. Folks are fast on the trigger...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - of course not. Added the semicolon. It is not the problem.

Comment: must be a stupid Visual C++ problem. g++ works fine with that...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - I noticed. But I am stuck with VS 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read [doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static)

foo.h

```
#include <cstddef>

class Foo
{
private:
    int bar;
public:
    static size_t const foo;
};
```

foo.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"

size_t const Foo::foo = sizeof(Foo::bar);
```

Comment: I am not asking for `sizeof(int)`. I am asking for `sizeof(m_x)`. This is not the same.

Comment: @mark edit for your case

Comment: @Stargateur did you test with VS 2015 or just GNU g++?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre http://ideone.com/sW594Y. It's standard C++ if VS don't handle it. I can't do anything.

Comment: the question is specifically tagged Visual Studio. Everyone knows it works with standard C++... finding a workaround would be a better idea.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I test it's compile on VS 2015 update 3. It's a very basic c++.

Comment: Hmm, I use VS 2015 Update 3 and my code does not compile. But your version does work! Thanks.